# Quiero que, al hacer clic en un botón, se envie un correo de verificación al correo introducido por el usuario. Como lo puedo hacer?

Tags: javascript, html, email

Tengo este código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Verificación de Correo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="verificationForm">
        <label for="email">Introduce tu correo electr&oacute;nico:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        <button type="submit">Enviar Correo de Verificaci&oacute;n</button>
    </form>
    <p id="statusMessage"></p>

    <script src="server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I me falta el de JS.
Me da igual que servidor de correo (si és necessario utilizarlo) utilizar, pero prefiero *nodemailer*, ya que lo instalé para probaar este proyecto.

Comment: ¿Y ya revistaste la [documentación](https://nodemailer.com/about/)?... ¿intentaste hacer algo?...

Comment: Yo le pregunté al ChatGPT a ver si me podia dar respuesta, pero al ver que no me funcionaba, decidí formular la pregunta, pero si, lo intenté yo solo, pero lo unico que conseguí, fue que me abriera la bandeja de entrada para enviar el email

Comment: `nodemailer` es una librería para aplicaciones de NodeJS. Lo que tu tienes es una web simple con un archivo de scripts, por lo cual no te funcionará. Lo que intentas hacer no se puede hacer directamente desde una página web. Se necesita un servidor que pueda realizar la petición de correo de forma correcta. Por ejemplo, un servidor escrito en NodeJS y que tenga instalado `nodemailer`como dependencia. También se puede hacer con PHP, teniendo un servidor web Apache. O podrías usar un servidor con Java (Tomcat). En fin, que siempre necesitarás usar un servidor que funcione detrás de tu página web

Comment: Sin embargo, podrías usar un servidor de un tercero, es decir, alguna API que se encargue de realizar la petición. De esta forma, desde tu script podrías simplemente consumir esta API, proveyendo la API Key o clave que te dan. Podrías leer [este post](https://medium.com/@davidkoller7117/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-no-backend-f968e16661eb) al respecto. Saludos

Comment: Enviar un email desde el cliente es algo que muchas veces va a fallar (si s que alguna llega a funcionar) por miles de razones. Lo que todo mundo hace es invocar a un servidor dónde se envía el correo. Cómo lo haces, bueno, la invocación puede ser un POST o una llamada a un WebService. Cómo envías el correo, depende de qué recursos tengas en el servidor, por ejemplo, qué lenguaje. No es igual en PHP que en node.js que en Delphi o .NET (por decir algunos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo uso php en esos casos.

aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
    $email = "usuario@gmail.com";
    $asunto = "asunto";
    $mensaje = "hola que tal?";

    $headers = "From: "."nombre del usuario"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: "."remitente@gmail.com";

    if(mail($email, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers)){
        echo "Bien";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```